# How to use a list of objects as map key in Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

In my Groovy application I have a function that is called several times every second, so I want to make it as fast as possible. This function receives a list of objects, then does some magic, and returns another list. The contents of the list returned depend on the content of the list passed to the function.

To make this faster I want to cache the list returned, because the magic done in the function does not change often. So in about 99% of all calls this function returns the same list for the same argument.

For the implementation of such a cache I want to use a map. The key of this map should be the list in the function's input argument, and the value of the map should be the list returned by the function for that input list.

My question is: what would be the most-optimal way to use a list of arbitrary objects as key for a Groovy map? I guess I could loop through all the keys in the map, and compare each list (the map's key) item by item. But that smells, I assume there should be a better and faster way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended with calling `hashCode()` for the input argument list. The nice thing is that I get the same hash value even for different lists, as long as their contents are the same. This is quite what I wanted, and I think that is reasonable fast.

Comment: This might create a problem. It is not guaranteed that `hashCode` will be same. [This test will always fail](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7170363/).

Comment: Yes I know that the order of the list is important. But in my case that is fine, the order will not change. And if it would, then it's also ok to have it cached two times...

Answer (score 2):

For Groovy 2.2.x, you can use [`@Memoized`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Memoized.html) AST for methods which does the caching internally.

```
@groovy.transform.Memoized
List getMeList(List params) {
    println "params passed $params"
    params.reverse()
}

def paramsList = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
getMeList(paramsList)
getMeList(paramsList)
getMeList(paramsList)
getMeList(paramsList)

def anotherList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
getMeList(anotherList)
getMeList(anotherList)
getMeList(anotherList)
getMeList(anotherList)
```

The difference is seen when it prints only once for the first call to the method and for the rest of the calls the result is got from cache.

Comment: Wow, that is really great, thanks. There is one catch though: I need to return the same list only in most of the cases, but not all. Whether or not the cached values should be retured is determined within the function. So is there something like a conditional `Memoized`?

Comment: Only values available to the annotations are `maxCacheSize` and `protectedCacheSize`, but you can have that logic to return the same list outside of this method and do that check before calling this memoized method which does the heavy lifting only once.